# Resize a Redshift cluster using CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-cloudformation

How we can resize a Redshift cluster by using CloudFormation?

Comment: Are http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/rs-resize-tutorial.html and http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-redshift-cluster.html any help at all? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @bouteillebleu I have gone through these docs. but it doesn't provides any details on resizing. I doubt updating a stack will update the configurations of cluster associated with it? Is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

AWS CloudFormation enables you to create and provision AWS infrastructure. A template specifies the desired resources and CloudFormation **creates** those resources.

However, **changing** an existing resource is out-of-scope for CloudFormation.

- If the resources were originally **deployed with CloudFormation**, then the template can be changed and the stack can be **updated**.
- If the resources were created **outside of CloudFormation**, then they **cannot be changed** by CloudFormation.